How to code so that the dashed gridlines look like the second picture
how do I code in latex so that I obtain the second picture below?
I’d like the dashed gridlines specifically to be like the second picture.
This is my attempt (first picture):
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
x=1cm, y=1cm,
ylabel = {$y$},
xlabel = {$x$},
ytick distance = 1,
xtick distance = 1,
minor x tick num=9,
minor y tick num=9,
ymin=-1,
ymax=4,
xmin=-0.9,
xmax=4,
major grid style={dashed, gray,thick},
minor grid style={densely dashed, black,very thin},
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}




Welcome.// Do you really need dashes? Varying gray may be the better alternative. Try e.g. black!20 or gray!50 etc. as colors.

What about major grid style={thick, densely dotted, gray}, minor grid style={very thin,  dash pattern=on 1pt off 0.5pt, black},?

Oh that works, thank you very much. :)

One step further as suggest @leanardriis in his comment:
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
x=1cm, y=1cm,
ylabel = {$y$},
xlabel = {$x$},
xtick distance = 1,
ytick distance = 1,
minor x tick num=9,
minor y tick num=9,
ymin=-1,
ymax=4,
xmin=-0.9,  xmax=4,
major grid style={dash pattern=on 0.2mm off 0.2mm, gray},               % <---
minor grid style={dash pattern=on 0.1mm off 0.1mm, black, ultra thin},  % <---
%
tick label style = {fill=white, inner sep=0.5pt,font=\scriptsize},  % new
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


